# calling and pass arguments to children component's function from parent component in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I found out that my argument passed from parent to child component through `refs` is either undefined or an actual event instead of what I passed in.

What is the right way to actually pass argument from parent to child component's function? I am using `refs` but seems its not really passing anything in term of function argument.

I show the case here:
https://codepen.io/adamchenwei/pen/gLMaPo/?editors=0010

Basically if you see the line where I wrote `console.log('child argument should be string');` it should be an argument actually passed instead of an event.

I wonder if I did things wrong.

For this scenario, I NEED to evaluate event in parent component and decide how I want to run the child function, with specific arguments passed in accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two way to access parent props in child component. you can achieve this in following two ways:-

1. Pass values into child component from parent via props
2. Set values in state and dispatch action from child to fetch values from state.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ref, I would use state and props:

```
parentDoThing(event) {
    const lifeTerms = {
      heaven: 'yeeeeey',
      hell: 'nooooooo',
    }
    if(event) {
      this.setState({ lifeTerms: heaven });
    } else {
      this.setState({ lifeTerms: hell});
    }
}

render() {    
    return (
      <section className="parent-comp"
        onClick={this.parentDoThings}>
        <ChildComponent
          lifeTerms={this.state.lifeTerms}/>
        <h1> Whats in App {this.state.text}</h1>
      </section>
);}
```

And on child component:

```
render() {    
    return (
      <section className="child">
        <section>this life is {this.state.life} </section>
        <button onClick={this.doChildThings.bind(this, this.props.lifeTerms)}> Button </button>
      </section>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved my issue by using `componentWillUpdate` in combine with using parent level `state` passed into child as `props` to trigger event inside the child, because I do not want any trigger inside the child to trigger the change provided by the parent.